# Ocaml function that takes a matrix (how to add without using matching)

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, fold

How to implement a function `sum_matrix` that can be used like this?

```
let m = [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]];; 
sum_matrix( [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]]);;
```

Without using matching, or comparing a list to an empty list. Supposed to use fold.

I understand how to do this wit two separate lists but the matrix aspect adds a level of depth that I do not understand. Also how does OCaml really accept parameters like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

```
let sum li = List.fold_left (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) 0 li
```

adds all elements of a list (they must be integer).

The function

```
let sum_apply f li = List.fold_left (fun acc elem -> acc + f elem) 0 li
```

computes the sum of applying `f` to each element of the input list: `sum_apply f [x;y;z]` is `f x + f y + f z` -- this could also be implemented using `sum` and `List.map`.

Do you see how to combine these two functions to get the sum of the integers in an `int list list`?

Comment: @amaranthist: hint: maybe the function you should pass to `sum_apply` is related to the other function in my message.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how using these two functions can help. Could you please explain in another manner?